# Cucumber 4 with Spring Boot and JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am using cucumber + cucumber-spring 4.1 for testing a SpringBoot 2.1 application.  This has scenarios that require the database to be rolled back between each scenario, but for the life of me cannot get it to work.

I have tried:

A base class with several annotations

```
`
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public abstract class SpringBootBaseIntegrationTest { .. } `
```

Stepdef classes like:

```
`
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
@Ignore
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@Transactional
public class DatabaseSteps extends SpringBootBaseIntegrationTest implements En { ... }
`
```

Features nd scenarios are annotated with @txn and the `'cucumber.api.spring'` glue is added.

My application has :

```
`
@EnableJms
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = false, value = "classpath:application.properties")
class Application implements CommandLineRunner { ... }
`
```

and I use standard JPA repositories.

My application.properties is:

```
`
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
#spring.h2.console.enabled=true
`
```

but whatever I do, in any combination, the data still remains between tests.

Can anyone shed light or managed a working set up?

Cheers

Comment: Can you put a break point in https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/spring/src/main/java/cucumber/api/spring/SpringTransactionHooks.java and see if the class is created and startTransaction and rollBackTransaction are invoked?

Comment: This is a working sample btw: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/spring-txn

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end. My Cucumber tests were entering the app via a number of different methods (JMS, Rest), and consequently the test did not own the transaction scope for data injected via these services.

Consequently, I am truncating the db tables in a before scenario hook for each test which seems to work fine